# How to add an icon to the options in react-select?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

Attempts to add an icon to option in react-select. I imported svg icons from the files `england.svg`, `germany.svg`. I created `customSingleValue` and put it in

```
<Select components={{ SingleValue: customSingleValue }} />
```

Labels are displayed, but the icons are not.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q19sor

```
import Select from 'react-select'
import { ReactComponent as IconFlagEngland } from "./england.svg";
import { ReactComponent as IconFlagGermany } from "./germany.svg";

const options = [
  { value: 'England', label: 'England', icon: <IconFlagEngland/> },
  { value: 'Germany', label: 'Germany', icon: <IconFlagGermany/> }
]

const customSingleValue = ({ options }) => (
    <div className="input-select">
        <div className="input-select__single-value">
            { options.icon && <span className="input-select__icon">{ options.icon }</span> }
            <span>{ options.label }</span>
        </div>
    </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Select
            defaultValue={ options [0] }
            options={ options }
            /*styles={ selectCustomStyles }*/
            /*onChange={ changeSelectHandler }*/
            components={ {SingleValue: customSingleValue } }
        />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have found a workaround to solve the issue. My technique is similar to that of **[@canda](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2553#issuecomment-390197214)**.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "England", label: "England", icon: "england.svg" },
  { value: "Germany", label: "Germany", icon: "germany.svg" }
];

const { Option } = components;
const IconOption = props => (
  <Option {...props}>
    <img
      src={require('./' + props.data.icon)}
      style={{ width: 36 }}
      alt={props.data.label}
    />
    {props.data.label}
  </Option>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        defaultValue={options[0]}
        options={options}
        components={{ Option: IconOption }}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: spot on fix, just using fontawesome icons, tvm

Comment: works for me, populates the drop down options, but the option selected is not getting displayed in the input box. I have specified value={selectedValue} and the selectedValue is getting populated correctly. Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anybody want to use icons with multiple selection in `react-select`, below code can be used:

```
const { MultiValue } = components;

const MultiValueOption = (props) => {
  return (
    <MultiValue {...props}>
      <img
        src={require("./" + props.data.icon)}
        style={{ width: 36 }}
        alt={props.data.label}
      />
      <span>{props.data.value}</span>
    </MultiValue>
  );
};

<Select
  options={options}
  components={{
    Option: IconOption,
    MultiValue: MultiValueOption,
  }}
  isMulti={true}
></Select>;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are not actually importing the SVGs. If you try to use `<IconFlagGermany/>` directly in your code anywhere, it will crash hard with this message :

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

It is currently not crashing because I think your `customSingleValue` function is not working as you intend it to (have not looked into it, but pretty sure it is bugged).

If you want to be able to import SVGs in this manner, you need to setup an appropriate loader in Webpack (or your chosen bundler). Maybe something like this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader

However, another solution is to properly export your SVGs as components, like in this demo forked from your code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5gvytm

Comment: No icon beside option text.

Comment: The current version of the question has the flag icon imported, so not sure what this answer was looking at when saying it wasn't imported.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did with the help of @Penny Liu

```
import React from 'react';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from './my-icon.svg';

const options = [
  {
    value: 'hello',
    label: 'Hello',
    Icon: MyIcon,
  },
  // ...
];

const { Option } = components;

function IconOption(props: any) {
  const {
    data: { label, Icon },
  } = props;

  return (
    <Option {...props}>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
        {Icon && <Icon />}
        <span>{label}</span>
      </div>
    </Option>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      components={{ Option: IconOption }}
      // ...
    />
  );
}
```

This method also worked

```
<SelectComponent
  options={options}
  getOptionLabel={(props: any) => {
    const { Icon, label } = props;
    return (
      <div tw="flex items-center gap-2">
        {Icon && <Icon />}
        <span>{label}</span>
      </div>
    ) as unknown as string;
  }}
/>
```