# How to show icons in dropdown menu (option tag) in React instead of getting [object Object]?

Tags: reactjs, icons, html-select

i tried like this in my code to have a dropdown menu with these icons.!

```
<select name="orientation">
  <option value="all"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/multiple-devices.png" /></option>
  <option value="landscape"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/iphone--v2.png" /></option>
  <option value="portrait"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/laptop.png" /></option>
  <option value="square"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/000000/name.png" /></option>
</select>
```

Instead i got like :

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

[pic of Output i got on webpage]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRHj9.png

> ***What can be done to show actual icons on menu??***

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `img` tag in option tag because tags are stripped.
you can use jquery like this example : https://codepen.io/antonandoff/pen/PmQvBz

and in react you can use react-select package like this :
[add image to react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449403/how-to-add-an-icon-to-the-options-in-react-select)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to change select component to antd popover -
https://ant.design/components/popover/
it is more suitable for what you're trying to do