# React select autocomplete search doesn't work

Tags: react-select

I'm using react select and i want to display in options icons ,But the search doesn't anymore work.
In my list options  i have orange but when i write orange in the select, return no options.

```
 <Select
                            placeholder="Select option"
                            value={selectedOption}
                            options={list?.map((e) => ({
                                ...e,
                                value: e?.id,
                                label: e?.name,
                                icon: (
                                    <div>
                                        <img
                                            style={{
                                                height: "40px",
                                                width: "50px",
                                                // borderRadius: "100%",
                                            }}
                                            src={e?.icon}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                ),
                            }))}
                            isClearable={true}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            name="option"
                            getOptionLabel={(e) => {
                                return (
                                    
                                            <div
                                                style={{
                                                    display: "flex",
                                                    alignItems: "center",
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                {e.icon}
                                                <span style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
                                                    {e.label}
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                       
                                    
                                );
                            }}
                        />
```

Comment: Did you miss isSearchable={true} on the select?

Comment: I added it ,But doesn't work .

Comment: I believe your getOptionLabel() is causing trouble. As per documentation getOptionLabel() is supposed to return a string but you are returning a component. From Docs `Failure to resolve to a string type can interfere with filtering and screen reader support.`

Comment: Yes , you are right . When i remove getOptionLabel ,It's work perfect .But how can i add the icons to my options ?

Comment: try this approach mentioned in the highest voted answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449403/how-to-add-an-icon-to-the-options-in-react-select